# android soap response parsing to json and parsing this json

Tags: android, json, parsing

i am getting 1 Json after one Soap webservice my response is like below... i am not able to how to parse it now... please help me out

```
 {
    "soap:Envelope": {
        "soap:Body": {
            "MRTHODNAMEResponse": {
                "METHODNAMEResult": {
                    "StatusCode": 0,
                    "STATUS": {
                        "content": 0,
                        "xmlns": "URL"
                    },                      

                    "Name": {
                        "content": "MR ABCD XYZ",
                        "xmlns": "URL"
                    },

                    "RMessage": {
                        "content": "successful.",
                        "xmlns": "URL"
                    }
                },
                "xmlns": "URL"
            }
        },
        "xmlns:xsi": "URL",
        "xmlns:soap": "URL",
        "xmlns:xsd": "URL"
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: currently i took JSONObject jObject3= new JSONObject(jsonString).getJSONObject("soap");
            JSONObject innerJObject = jObject3.getJSONObject("soap");

Comment: but getting No value for soap

Comment: i think you should write JSONObject jObject3= new JSONObject(jsonString).getJSONObject("soap:Envelope");
"soap:Envelope" in place of "soap"

Comment: `.getJSONObject("soap")` ? you should use `.getJSONObject("soap:Envelope")` then `.getJSONObject("soap:Body")`